# How To get the value from a Json response

Tags: android, json, web-services

My json resposnse from webservice is like
 `{"d":"[{\"userid\":507}]"}` in Android. I need to get the userid from this response. How is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: Please look at the example . [Anroid JSON Parsing Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Comment: I didn't get the exact answer for my solution. That's why i posted this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last i got the exact answer for my solution . I got the userid from my response using this code`

```
       result=(String) jobj.getString("d");
       JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject js=arr.getJSONObject(0);
        String userid=js.getString("Userid");`
```

Answer (score 2):

try this way

```
private void parseJson(String response) {
        try{
            JSONObject main = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray d = main.getJSONArray("d");

            for (int i = 0; i <d.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject item = d.getJSONObject(i);
                System.out.println("userid : " + item.getString("userid"));
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```